# Posicionamento do eixo X usando MatPlotLib em python 3.x

Tags: python

Fiz o codigo abaixo para imprimir um grafico porem preciso que a o eixo x fique no ponto(0,0). Ja tentei vários caminhos e nao consegui podem ajudar? Acredito que seja algo simples mas nao consegui achar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

history=[0.8,0.5,0.3,0.1,0,-0.1,-0.4,-0.5,-0.8,-2]

epp = range(1, len(history) + 1)

pl.plot(epp, history, 'r')

tt='Titulo do Grafico'

pl.title(tt)

pl.xlabel('eixo X')

pl.ylabel('eixo Y')

pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

não sei exatamente o que você quer dizer com "preciso que a o eixo x fique no ponto(0,0)".

Se você está falando em **mostrar os eixos da origem XY**, você pode fazer isso usando `axvline` e `axhline` para plotar uma linha vertical e horizontal, respectivamente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
history=[0.8,0.5,0.3,0.1,0,-0.1,-0.4,-0.5,-0.8,-2]
epp = range(1, len(history) + 1)
pl.plot(epp, history, 'r')
tt='Titulo do Grafico'
pl.title(tt)
pl.xlabel('eixo X')
pl.ylabel('eixo Y')

# código adicional
pl.axvline(0, color='k')
pl.axhline(0, color='k')

pl.show()
```

Gráfico gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por outro lado, se você está falando em **fazer com que o canto inferior esquerdo da figura represente o ponto XY (0, 0)**, você pode usar `xlim` e `ylim` para configurar os limites de cada eixo (note que isso vai cortar parte da sua série de dados que contém valores negativos):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
history=[0.8,0.5,0.3,0.1,0,-0.1,-0.4,-0.5,-0.8,-2]
epp = range(1, len(history) + 1)
pl.plot(epp, history, 'r')
tt='Titulo do Grafico'
pl.title(tt)
pl.xlabel('eixo X')
pl.ylabel('eixo Y')

# código adicional
pl.xlim(left=0)
pl.ylim(bottom=0)

pl.show()
```

Gráfico gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]